# Does std::map<whatever,double> automatically zero values?

Tags: c++, std

If I write:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, double> q;
    q[3] += 4;
    return 0;
}
```

Can I be assured q[3] is 4, and not that q[3] is 4 + (some random uninitialized garbage from memory)?

Comment: downvoted because any serious doc for `map::operator[]` should cover this

Comment: @tobi303: It's buried quite deep though.

Comment: [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) says *If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.* Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Even more than that, std::vector<double>(100) would be a vector of a hundred zeroes.

Comment: Is that still true for C++11?

Comment: @Bathsheba If you look into example for http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at it explicitly mentions that, I doubt it is buried

Comment: @Slava: Let's resist this becoming some kind of bragging contest. Answering questions well is the best way to show off, should you feel the need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized
>   (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and
>   a reference to it is returned.

So you can count on the value being initialized to zero.

EDIT:

The quote above refers to the situation before C++11. The wording for C++11 and later is harder to understand, but here is what I think is the operative sentence:

> When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy
>   constructed from key and the mapped value being value-initialized.

The same parenthetical comment in the first quote also applies to the term "value-initialized" here (see [the page on value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)), so it will still zero initialize values of primitive types.

Comment: OK, so zero initialized if no default constructor exists. Perfect.

Comment: A formal standard reference would be the icing on the cake here, but +1 anyway

Comment: @Carbon, not sure thats what it actually says. IF there is no default constructor for an object i expect it to fail

Comment: its not zero initialized, but it is default initialized. If no default constructor exists you cannot use `operator[]`, though you can still use the map

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Do feel cree to edit cppreference - I have on a couple of occasions.

Comment: @Bathsheba My comment is not meant to indicate an error with cppreference. I meant to say the passage quoted in the answer is taken from a block labeled (until C++11).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That's reassuring; cppreference is *extremely* well-maintained.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Edited. Is that better?

Answer (score 4):

If `q[3]` does not exist in the map, then that record is created for you and the value **is** initialised to zero.

Your code is safe.